# using webbrowser to Interact with a Flash control?

Tags: c#, flash, controls, browser

using Automation (SHDocVw, MSHTML or something else?) or a WebBrowser control:
1)Is it possible to interrogate a flash control to discover its elements?  For example, "http://demo.garanti.com.tr/bireysel_demo/main.html" there are flash buttons.  Can I determine there "ID"s?
 2)Given the "ID" names of elements in a flash control, is it possible to click and/or select them?

Comment: is there anyone  who has a mind ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes. Just implement the right functionality in Flash and use ExternalInterface to call Flash methods.

Check out the documentation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

or an easy example:
http://jodieorourke.com/view.php?id=122&blog=news